# Jeditable is not working on dynamically created table rows

Tags: javascript, html

my last question was about how to add a row to a table dynamically. That one got solved pretty quickly and I'm happy with the result. However the table I built needs to be editable with JEditable, this does work in the original row but not in the dynamically added one.
Any solutions to that? My Code is as follows:
My HTML table:

```
    <tbody class="b1" id="b2">
        <tr id="form1">
            <td rowspan="2"><input type="checkbox" name="chk"/></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><span class="charcounter" name="Flight_Nr" /></td>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><span class="editable-select-REG" name="REG"/></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><span class="editable-select" name="equip_code"/></td>
            <td rowspan="2"></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><span class="checkbox" name="ERK"/></td>
            <td><span class="charcounter" name="PIC"/></td>
            <td><span class="charcounter" name="BTM"/></td>
            <td><span class="charcounter" name="AG_1"/><span class="charcounter" name="AG_2"/><span class="charcounter" name="AG_3"/></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><span class="editable_textarea" name="DEP"/></td>
            <td><span class="timepicker" name="ETD_1"/></td>
            <td><span class="timepicker" name="ETA_1"/></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><span class="editable_textarea" name="DEST_1"/></td>
            <td><span class="timepicker" name="ETD_2"/></td>
            <td><span class="timepicker" name="ETA_2"/></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><span class="editable_textarea" name="DEST_2"/></td>
            <td><span class="timepicker" name="ETD_3"/></td>
            <td><span class="timepicker" name="ETA_3"/></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><span class="editable_textarea" name="DEST_3"/></td>
            <td><span class="timepicker" name="ETD_4"/></td>
            <td><span class="timepicker" name="ETA_4"/></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><span class="editable_textarea" name="DEST_4"/></td>
            <td><span class="timepicker" name="ETE"/></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><span class="editable_textarea" name="auftrag_1"/></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><span class="editable_textarea" name="auftrag_2"/></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><span class="editable_textarea" name="cancel_by"/></td>
            <td rowspan="2"><span class="editable_textarea" name="note"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="form2">
            <td><span class="charcounter" name="P"/></td>
            <td><span class="charcounter" name="BTL"/></td>
            <td><span class="editable_textarea" name="ACM"/></td>
            <td><span class="timepicker" name="ATD_1"/></td>
            <td><span class="timepicker" name="ATA_1"/></td>
            <td><span class="timepicker" name="ATD_2"/></td>
            <td><span class="timepicker" name="ATA_2"/></td>
            <td><span class="timepicker" name="ATD_3"/></td>
            <td><span class="timepicker" name="ATA_3"/></td>
            <td><span class="timepicker" name="ATD_4"/></td>
            <td><span class="timepicker" name="ATA_4"/></td>
            <td><span class="timepicker" name="ATE"/></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </form>
</table>
<input type="button" onclick="insertRow('t2')" value="Reihe hinzufügen"/>
<input type="button" onclick="deleteRow('t2')" value="Reihe entfernen"/>
<input type="button" name="accept_changes" value="Änderungen übernehmen"/>
```

and my insertRow.js:

```
    function insertRow(tableId){

// Get a reference to the table
let tableRef = document.getElementById(tableId);

let firstRowLength = tableRef.rows.namedItem('form1').cells.length;
let secondRowLength = tableRef.rows.namedItem('form2').cells.length;

// Insert a row at the end of the table
let newRow = tableRef.insertRow(-1);


// for inserting 1. row
for (i = 0; i < firstRowLength; i++) {
    // Get previous cell
    let prevCell = tableRef.rows.namedItem('form1').cells.item(i);

    // Insert a cell in the row at index i
    let newCell = newRow.insertCell(i);

    // Append a text node to the cell
    newCell.innerHTML = prevCell.innerHTML;
    newCell.rowSpan = prevCell.rowSpan;
    newCell.class = prevCell.class;
    newCell.name = prevCell.name;
}

// Insert a row at the end of the table second time
let newRow2 = tableRef.insertRow(-1);
        
// for inserting 2. row
for (i = 0; i < secondRowLength; i++) {
    // Get previous cell
    let prevCell = tableRef.rows.namedItem('form2').cells.item(i);

    // Insert a cell in the row at index i
    let newCell = newRow2.insertCell(i);

    // Append a text node to the cell
    newCell.innerHTML = prevCell.innerHTML;
}
```

Any clues as to what I might do to keep everything editable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asked the DEV of JEditable… really Basic solution just refresh the js everytime you move over the object:

```
 $(table).mouseenter(function() {
```

Just put that below the

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
```

and it works like a charm. now everytime you add a new row you just have to move your mouse over the table and it works.